# how to convert int to chrono milliseconds

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I have a variable which is of type milliseconds and i want to set it equal to an equation. Here is what ive done so far. It compiles and runs but when it hits this line it stops entering the if statement below.

```
time = duration<int>(750-(lvl*50));
```

another thing to note is that i do have an if statement which may also be part of the issue that i'm comparing different data types. here is that if statement:

```
if(time_since_last >= time) {
```

the time since last variable is the difference in time of different 2 high_resolution_clock::now()

Comment: First please create a [MRE]. Then please post the expected behavior, the observed behavior and the error messages (if any). "messed up" is not a description of the problem.

Comment: Here is a video chrono tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M  It will cost you an hour.  But it will help you understand how the chrono library works.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try something like this. For converting an integer value to chrono in milliseconds use `std::chrono::milliseconds(value);`

```
auto old_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(500));
auto new_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
auto time_since_last = std::chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(new_time - old_time);   
cout << time_since_last.count();

int value = 1000;
auto time = std::chrono::milliseconds(value);
cout << "   " <<time.count();

if (time_since_last >= time) {
    /* do something */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use intervals in comparison. Use the absolute values instead. For example:

```
next_time = curr_time + duration<int>( ... etc ... );
if( time > next_time ) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <chrono>
...
milliseconds time = (750ms-(lvl*50ms));
```

I am assuming you were controlling some delay (time) with an integer (lvl)